# not able to compile wxpython-cffi on macOS with pypy3

Tags: macos, matplotlib, wxpython, doxygen, pypy

I'm trying to follow/modify [these instructions](https://pythonfiles.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/making-matplotlib-work-with-pypy/) to get matplotlib compiled on pypy3, but when I try to compile `wxpython-cffi` with `pypy3 build.py dox` I get this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "build.py", line 1650, in <module>
>     main(sys.argv[1:])
>   File "build.py", line 164, in main
>     function(options, args)
>   File "build.py", line 665, in cmd_dox
>     _doDox('xml')
>   File "build.py", line 657, in _doDox
>     pwd = pushDir(posixjoin(wxDir(), 'docs/doxygen'))
>   File "build.py", line 422, in __init__
>     os.chdir(newDir)
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/tmp/docs/doxygen'
> ```

The steps I followed are:

1. installing pypy3 with brew: `brew install pypy3`
2. trying to install matplotlib with `pip_pypy3` but getting [this long error message](https://pastebin.com/aCnSwT1b)
3. trying to install `wxpython` with `pip_pypy3 install wxpython` and getting [another very long error message](https://pastebin.com/AMB238rJ)
4. Download `wxpython-cffi`: `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/amauryfa/wxpython-cffi`
5. installing `wxWidgets` with `brew`: `brew install wxWidgets`
6. `which doxygen` --> `/usr/local/bin/doxygen`
7. `export DOXYGEN=/usr/local/bin/doxygen`
8. and finally `pypy3 build.py dox` which results the error above
9. changing the line `657` of `build.py` from `pwd = pushDir(posixjoin(wxDir(), 'docs/doxygen'))` to `pwd = pushDir('/usr/local/bin')` results in a completely different error:

> ```
> Running command: dox
> ./regen.sh xml
> /bin/sh: ./regen.sh: No such file or directory
> Command './regen.sh xml' failed with exit code 127.
> ```

I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it. the final goal is to get the matplotlib installed on pypy3, so out of the box solutions also would do.

**P.S.** I'm not sure if my tags are appropriate. I would appreciate if the moderators could let me know if they need to be modified/removed

Comment: Please don't include images from 'pastebin' but include the actual textual error messages (the reference might not be persistent and people don't like clicking on links). Looks like an creation error in the script. i.e. the mentioned directory is not created (permissions?). I don't think the problem is in doxygen but in the. non doxygen,  script (build.py).

Comment: @albert thanks for the reply: 1. I put the error messages in pastebin, as they were somehow irrelevant to the main question, and they are very long. I don't know any better place to past such a long error message please let me know if you have better options. 2. could you be so kind to take a look at the script and help me know where is the problem?

Comment: I don´t know pypy and mac, so I cannot help directly. I was writing it from the doxygen prespective.

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib and PyPy is a known pain point on OSX, we have had multiple reporters but since the PyPy team does not have an OSX developer we cannot fix it on our own. See https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2327 or any of the other matplotlib issues on the PyPy issue tracker.

It would be great if someone capable of working through this with us would step up and help us fix it, reach out with a response to any of the multiple issues or on IRC at #pypy

Comment: Thanks for the post. Has anybody ever succeed to install matplotlib on pypy on any other operating system rather than macOS? that should be a good starting point I guess! That's what I have tried above. if we solve these small issues one by one I think we will get there finally.

Comment: for developer who do not possess a mac maby installing macOS on virtualbox is a good thing to try. just google "hackintosh virtualbox"

Comment: @Foad other platforms do not use that matplotlib code path, only MacOS.Other platforms have no issues that we know of with matplotlib + PyPy